# Android app becomes black after several days, how to debug

Tags: android, debugging, tablet, kiosk-mode

I'm developing an app that should run 24 hours 7 days a week, in a kind of kiosk mode. Normally it works fine, but after 1 week or 2 the screen turns mostly black showing the action bar at the top of the screen with the logo of the app to the top left, instead of the GUI that I have specified. I have disabled the action bar in the style used by the activities of the app.

As this app is supposed to be run on tablets and most tablets (all that I have tested) need more power than the normal USB port of a computer can provide (as the screen of the tablet should be ON at all time) the problem becomes pretty hard for me to debug. As I can't have a tablet connected to the computer for weeks on end running the app. How do I even begin to debug this?

Comment: you should track log and exceptions remotely , you can write it in a file or directly get in your email. there are libraries who supports remote debugging you can try them as well.

Comment: For example, use Google Analytics with specific log messages, or something like www.crashlytics.com